# Problem with FindDevices["Camera"]

Tags: interoperability, data-acquisition, input-devices

I have a problem with `FindDevices["Camera"]` function. When I try to execute it I get this:

```
In[1]:= FindDevices["Camera"]

During evaluation of In[1]:= LibraryFunction::libload: The function DiscoverCameras was not loaded from the file C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.1\SystemFiles\Links\IMAQTools\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\IMAQTools.dll. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= LibraryFunction::libload: The function CameraOpen was not loaded from the file C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.1\SystemFiles\Links\IMAQTools\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\IMAQTools.dll. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= LibraryFunction::libload: The function CameraSetResolution was not loaded from the file C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.1\SystemFiles\Links\IMAQTools\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\IMAQTools.dll. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= General::stop: Further output of LibraryFunction::libload will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= Riffle::list: List expected at position 1 in Riffle[$Failed[],{}]. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= Riffle::list: List expected at position 1 in Riffle[$Failed[],{}]. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= Riffle::argtu: Riffle called with 1 argument; 2 or 3 arguments are expected. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= GatherBy::list: List expected at position 1 in GatherBy[Riffle[Riffle[$Failed[],{}]],#1[[1]]&]. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= GatherBy::list: List expected at position 1 in GatherBy[Riffle[Riffle[$Failed[],{}]],#1[[1]]&]. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= GatherBy::list: List expected at position 1 in GatherBy[IMAQTools`Private`indexList[Riffle[Riffle[$Failed[],{}]]],IMAQTools`Private`indexList[#1[[1]]&]]. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= General::stop: Further output of GatherBy::list will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= Part::pkspec1: The expression Riffle[$Failed[],{}] cannot be used as a part specification. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= Part::partw: Part 2 of Riffle[Riffle[$Failed[],{}]] does not exist. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in $Failed[][[Riffle[$Failed[],{}]]]<> (Riffle[Riffle[$Failed[], {}]][[2]]). >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in $Failed[][[Riffle[$Failed[],{}]]]<> (Riffle[Riffle[$Failed[], {}]][[2]]). >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= Set::pkspec1: The expression Riffle[$Failed[],{}] cannot be used as a part specification. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= Part::partw: Part 1 of $Failed[] does not exist. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= Part::partw: Part 2 of #1[[1]]& does not exist. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= General::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in $Failed[][[1]]<> ((#1[[1]] & )[[2]]). >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= General::stop: Further output of StringJoin::string will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= Set::partw: Part 1 of $Failed[] does not exist. >>

Out[1]= {}
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting *Mathematica*, and possibly your computer as well? You might also have a corrupt configuration file; possibly you could try to reset *Mathematica* to its default configuration as described on [this Wolfram Support page](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464).

Comment: It does not help :(

Comment: Have you checked whether you have that `IMAQTools.dll` file at the path that is indicated in the very first error you get? I checked on my system and I did find it exactly where your error suggests. If you don't have the file, or the path doesn't exist on your computer, that would suggest to me that your installation is incomplete or corrupted, in which case you might want to contact Wolfram Support.

Comment: Yes, I did checked that. I even asked Wolfram Support to send me the whole IMAQTools folder, in case mine was somewhat corrupted. It did not help.

Comment: Unfortunately I fear that only WRI will be able to assist you, and thus I vote to close the question as essentially unanswerable in this forum. It seems that something is seriously amiss with your installation. I have seen this message when the real reason behind it was an "access denied" error, but I doubt that applies in your case.